# man’s : adjective or noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

> ,,,but when his trunk was close to the tailor, he discharged the muddy water full in the man’s face. So the tailor was taught a good lesson.

In the above example, is *man’s* not an adjective?

Comment: Why do you think it's an adjective, and not a possessive noun?

Answer (score 2):

It's a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners), of [the possessive noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_determiners) form.  Some lump determiners with adjectives (which has been the traditional view); some insist that they are their own part of speech.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Grammarians frequently disagree on terminology, but in this case "the man's" can be replaced by "his" as a grammatically identical replacement save for being a pronoun in place of a noun.  As a pronoun, I was taught to call it a "possessive adjective."

And that is what "man's" is: a possessive *nominal* adjective (as opposed to being a *pronominal* adjective).

Whether or not one chooses to call it an adjective, its function is adjectival.